# magento attribute

Tags: magento-1.9

I have an item that fits for (toyota camry 2007-2013) & for (Ford explorer 2012-16)
and I want to use attributes to help for search & layered navigation.

so if someone searched for example

toyota camry 2007

or

toyota camry 2010

or

Ford explorer 2016

he will get this item

however, I don't know how to use attribute to achieve this

I have made three attributes

1. Car Brand selected (Toyota, Ford)
2. Car Name  Selected (Camry, explorer)
3. Car model Selected (2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016)

but I was not able to separate the car model for each car, so it will be shown for any model (2007-2016) for each car

So what is the right way to use attribute to achieve what I need ?

Answer (score 0):

- If you want these attributes displayed in the frontend check each attribute's options and enable "display in frontend".
- After creating the attribute you should add that attribute to the default attribute set (go to attributes sets and drag&drop your unassigned attributes).
- Select a value for each product (i.e. the `toyota camry 2010` should have all three values `toyota`, `camry` and `2010` selected.)

And you should see your attributes displayed in the frontend.